# try makeSceneTransitionAnimation in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, transition

while learning kotlin i try to create makeSceneTransitionAnimation for image transition but it doesn't work like in java, this is my code from **Adapter class**

```
itemView.imageContent.setOnClickListener {
    val i = Intent(context, ImagePreviewActivity::class.java)
    i.putExtra("IMAGE", item.content)
    val trans = context.getString(R.string.transition)
    val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
            Activity(), itemView.imageContent, trans
    )
    context.startActivity(i, options.toBundle())
}
```

this is my logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.Window.hasFeature(int)' on a null object reference
     at android.app.ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(ActivityOptions.java:709)
     at android.app.ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(ActivityOptions.java:648)
     at android.app.ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(ActivityOptions.java:622)
     at android.support.v4.app.ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(ActivityOptionsCompat.java:172)
     at com.docotel.binmaspublic.module.report.ReportAdapter$ViewHolder$bind$2.onClick(ReportAdapter.kt:130)
```

sorry if you found this as a duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Java vs Kotlin.

`R.string.transition` is an ID for a String resource, it is not the actual value.
To get the value you need to use:

```
context.getString(R.string.transition)
```

Comment: ok i'm wrong about that, what about NullPointer i get in line **val options** ?

Answer (score 0):

On this line :

```
val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
        Activity(), itemView.imageContent, trans
)
```

You are creating a new Android Activity instance. But you must pass your current activity (probably `this@MyActivity` in this case).

**Edito:**
Assuming `itemView.imageContent` is the imageView, and `item.content` a string. You can implement a calllback in your adapter and move the code in the OnClickListener to the adapter creation.
Smething like this.

```
class MyAdapter : YourBaseAdapter(/*args*/)  {

    var onItemClickListener = { view: ImageView, content: String -> }

   ///...
   itemView.imageContent.setOnClickListener {
    onItemClickListener(itemView.imageContent, item.content)
   }
   //...
} //end of MyAdapter
```

and in your adapter class initialisation set:

```
myAdapter.onItemClickListener = { view, content ->
    val i = Intent(context, ImagePreviewActivity::class.java)
    i.putExtra("IMAGE", content)
    val trans = context.getString(R.string.transition)
    val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
        theReferenceOfYourActivity, view, trans
    )
    context.startActivity(i, options.toBundle())

}
```

You can also pass the reference of your activity to your adapter constructor, but I not recommend it.

---

From *makeSceneTransitionAnimation* doc :

> Create an ActivityOptions to transition between Activities using cross-Activity scene animations. This method carries the position of multiple shared elements to the started Activity. The position of the first element in sharedElements will be used as the epicenter for the exit Transition. The position of the associated shared element in the launched Activity 
>   will be the epicenter of its entering Transition.
>
> This requires android.view.Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS to be enabled on the calling Activity to cause an exit transition. The same must be in the called Activity to get an entering transition.
>
> **Parameters:**
>   `activity` - The Activity whose window contains the shared elements.
>   `sharedElements` - The names of the shared elements to transfer to the called Activity and their associated Views. The Views must each have a unique shared element name.
>
> **Returns:**
>   Returns a new ActivityOptions object that you can use to supply these options as the options Bundle when starting an activity.

Comment: but this action is from adapter class, so i can't do **this@MyActivity**

Comment: Then your adapter needs to have a reference to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
You need to pass context by casting it to activity context like

```
val options:ActivityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(context as Activity,holder.itemView.deliveryImageIV,context.getString(R.string.cardtransition))
```